# Solving steady state temperature distribution of circular plate

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, boundary-value-problem

I am working through some past papers in preparation to an upcoming exam and I am stuck on the last part of this question.

We have a circular plate of radius $a$. The temperature distribution, $u(\rho,\phi)$, has boundary conditions $u(a,\phi) = T_1$ when $0<\phi<\pi $ and $T_2$ when $ \pi<\phi<2\pi$.
The steady state temperature distribution satisfies the Laplace equation.

I have used separation of variables to reduce the equation to two ODE's which I solved to find the general solution to be $u(\rho,\phi)=\sum C_\lambda \exp(\lambda\phi)\phi^\lambda$

The question then asks us to find the Fourier series for $u(a,\phi)$. I did this by finding the series for the two boundary conditions which resulted in: $u(a,\phi) = \frac{(T_1-T_2)}{2}+\sum\frac{((-1^m)-1)(T_2-T_1)sin(m\phi)}{\pi m}$
(Noted that I am not 100% sure this is correct)

The final part of the question, and the source of my problem, asks us to find an expression for $u(\rho,\phi)$ as an infinite series using the previous answer. 
I do not understand how to form a general solution using this - I cannot see how the Fourier series is of any relevance to a general solution as it doesnt appear to help us find $C_\lambda$ or $\lambda$ itself. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will split the problem into two pieces, at the end will use both pieces to generate the answer

> FOURIER TRANSFORM

Imagine a function of the form

$$
f(\phi) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
T_1,& 0 < \phi < \pi \\
T_2,& \pi < \phi < 2\pi \end{array} \right.
$$

This function is defined in the interval $(0, 2\pi)$, but we can always make a periodic *odd* extension such that $f(-\phi) = f(\phi)$. This selection is completely arbitrary, you can try to do it with an even extension, it will work out just the same. The period of this function is then $T = 4\pi$, and the [Fourier Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) is simply

$$
f(\phi) = \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty}B_n \sin\left(\frac{n \phi}{2}\right) \tag{1}\label{1}
$$

with

$$
B_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} {\rm d}\phi~f(\phi)\sin\left(\frac{n \phi}{2}\right)
$$

I will strongly encourage you to solve this integral, for now I will just write the result

$$
B_n = \frac{2}{n\pi}\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 
(1 - (-1)^{n/2})(T_1 - T_2), & n \mbox{ even} \\
T_1 + T_2, & n \mbox{ odd}
\end{array}\right. 
$$

Below is an example with $T_1 = 1$, $T_2 = 3$ and truncating the sum at $n = 50$

[image]

> LAPLACE EQUATION

If $u(\rho,\phi) = R(\rho)\Phi(\phi)$ represents the steady state solution for the temperature profile, then $\nabla^2u = 0$, which can be rewritten as

$$
\frac{\rho}{R(\rho)}\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\rho}\left(\rho \frac{{\rm d}R(\rho)}{{\rm d}\rho} \right) = -\frac{1}{\Phi(\phi)}\frac{{\rm d}^2\Phi(\phi)}{{\rm d}\phi^2} = m^2
$$

I assumed that the constant must be positive, otherwise you'll have a hard time trying to reconcile the boundary conditions for this geometry. Indeed, it must be true that

$$
u(a, \phi) = f(\phi) = R(a)\Phi(\phi)
$$

So, if we impose that $R(a) = 1$, then $\Phi(\phi) = f(\phi)$ from the previous step

$$
\Phi_n(\phi) = B_n \sin\left(\frac{n\phi}{2}\right)\tag{2}\label{2}
$$

With $m = n/2$. Now we only requiere to calculare $R(\rho)$,

$$
R(\rho) = C_-\left(\frac{\rho}{a} \right)^{-n/2} + C_+\left(\frac{\rho}{a} \right)^{n/2} \tag{3}\label{3}
$$

we requiere that the temperature is finite at the origin, so $C_- = 0$, and that $R(a) = 1$ which leads to $C_+ = 1$

> EVERYTHING TOGETHER

If we put together $\ref{2}$ and $\ref{3}$ we arrive to the conclusion that

$$
u(\rho,\phi) = \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty}B_n \sin\left(\frac{n\phi}{2}\right) \left(\frac{\rho}{a}\right)^{n/2}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed answer! Its makes good sense apart your derivation of (3). Would you be kind enough to explain where this has come from?

Comment: It comes from solving the equation

$$
\frac{\rho}{R(\rho)}\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\rho}\left(\rho \frac{{\rm d}R(\rho)}{{\rm d}\rho} \right) = -m^2 
$$